# Log Doctrine Insert/Update Statements ony for some entities

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, monolog

I want to log all Insert/Update statements like we can do with the with these settings in config.yml - but only for **certain entites**.

```
   doctrine:
      dbal:
         connections: 
            default:
               logging:   true
...
   monolog:
    handlers:
      doctrine:
            channels: doctrine
            type: stream
            path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%_doctrine.log" #(to file as a test)
```

I also created some Event Listeners and Subscribers (onFlush/onUpdate) - but then I cannot get the SQL anymore.

Any ideas?

Comment: since doctrine has a(n) sql logger, you should be able to decorate it and write the queries for your certain entities somewhere else ... ?

Comment: my first thought was rather extracting your desired data from the log using for example ` less log | grep "INSERT INTO my_table" `